# Http POST in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

As I have gone through the examples,I have come across only asynchronous http web request having callback methods,like:-

```
    private void getList(string restApiPath, Dictionary<string, string> output, Type type, string label)
    {

        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restApiPath);
        path = restApiPath;
        labelValue = label;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        webRequest.ContentType = Globals.POST_CONTENT_TYPE;
        webRequest.Headers["st"] = MPFPConstants.serviceType;

        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(result =>
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);

            // Create the post data
            string reqData = Utils.getStringFromList(output);


            string encode = RESTApi.encodeForTokenRequest(reqData);

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encode);

            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();


            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallbackForSpecificConditions), request);

        }, webRequest);
    }

    private void GetResponseCallbackForSpecificConditions(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
      //code
     }
```

Kindly Suggest me if we can make a synchronous httpwebrequest for wp8?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this, it works in a Desktop app:

```csharp
                using (Stream TextRequestStream = UsedWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    TextRequestStream.Write(ByteArray, 0, ByteArray.Length);
                    TextRequestStream.Flush();
                }               
                HttpWebResponse TokenWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)UsedWebRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream ResponseStream = TokenWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader ResponseStreamReader = new StreamReader(ResponseStream);
                string Response = ResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                ResponseStreamReader.Close();
                ResponseStream.Close();
```

Comment: There is no method BeginResponse() .So, webRequest.BeginResponse() dosen't work and have to use webRequest.BeginGetResponse()

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/)?

sample POST code looks like,

```
RestClient _authClient = new RestClient("https://sample.com/account/login");
RestRequest _credentials = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
_credentials.AddCookie(_cookie[0].Name, _cookie[0].Value);
_credentials.AddParameter("userLogin", _username, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
_credentials.AddParameter("userPassword", _password, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
_credentials.AddParameter("submit", "", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
RestResponse _credentialResponse = (RestResponse)_authClient.Execute(_credentials);
Console.WriteLine("Authentication phase Uri   : " + _credentialResponse.ResponseUri);
```